# vm machines cannot ping each other via bridge network

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I created vhost1 and vhost2 by using virt-manager which run on a Ubuntu server 22.04
The Host and VMS connected via a bridge network. So here's the thing:
The `ping` working fine between Host and VMS, but it doesn't work between VMS(vhost1 and vhost2)

Network configuration of Host:

br0:  `192.168.110.161/24`

/etc/netplan/netcfg.yaml

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp24s0f1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      macaddress: aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.110.161/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.110.1
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 223.6.6.6
      interfaces:
          - enp24s0f1
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
```

bridge:

```bash
(base) root@qlsj:/etc/netplan# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.aabbcc112233   yes     enp24s0f1
                            vnet6
                            vnet7
docker0     8000.0242b2287cce   no      veth1beee8b
                            veth6554059
virbr0      8000.525400dcd61a   no      vnet2
                            vnet4
(base) root@qlsj:/etc/netplan#
```

kvm vhost1 nic:

```xml
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:19:ab:92"/>
  <source bridge="br0"/>
  <target dev="vnet6"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net1"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x07" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

kvm vhost2 nic:

```xml
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:81:59:a2"/>
  <source network="host-bridge" portid="72753e9d-2408-4858-b8b7-806b3666afa0" bridge="br0"/>
  <target dev="vnet7"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net1"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x09" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

Network configuration of vhost1:

enp9s0: `192.168.110.204/24`

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    # interface name
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.110.204/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.110.1
          metric: 99
      nameservers:
        addresses: [223.6.6.6,223.5.5.5]
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2
```

Host ping vhost1:

```bash
(base) root@qlsj:~# ping 192.168.110.204
PING 192.168.110.204 (192.168.110.204) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.110.204: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.398 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.110.204: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.280 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.110.204: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.253 ms
^C
--- 192.168.110.204 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2025ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.253/0.310/0.398/0.062 ms
(base) root@qlsj:~#
```

Network configuration of vhost2:

enp7s0:  `192.168.110.169/24`

```yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    # interface name
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.110.169/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.110.1
          metric: 101
      nameservers:
        # name server to bind
        addresses: [223.6.6.6,223.5.5.5]
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2
```

Host ping vhost2:

```bash
(base) root@qlsj:~# 
(base) root@qlsj:~# ping 192.168.110.169
PING 192.168.110.169 (192.168.110.169) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.110.169: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.110.169: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms
^C
--- 192.168.110.169 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.244/0.318/0.392/0.074 ms
(base) root@qlsj:~#
```

vhost1 ping vhost2:

```bash
qlsj@vhost1:~$ ping 192.168.110.169
PING 192.168.110.204 (192.168.110.204) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.110.161 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 192.168.110.161 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
From 192.168.110.161 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered
^C
--- 192.168.110.204 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2034ms

qlsj@vhost1:~$
```

route of Host:

```bash
(base) root@qlsj:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.110.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.110.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
(base) root@qlsj:~#
```

Both Host and vms configuate with`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, policy of `iptables FORWARD chain` is `ACCEPT`

I have no idea what to do. I tried lots of things, It doesn't work.

Please forgive  my grammatical mistakes, I am not good at English.

If anything I can provide, Please comment below.

Comment: You could do this to confirm it's because of Docker (disrupting just Docker): as root user do `sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0` and try again between the two VMs.

Comment: @A.B
It works.  Thank you very much for your answer.